R plot_ly produces inconsistent results with markdown + flexdashboard + crosstalk
I am trying to use flexdashboard and crosstalk with Markdown for effective presentation of Health Care Quality Indicators on a set of web pages without using Shiny. I believe this can have rather positive implications for public institutions, where running server apps may pose relevant operational questions and security issues. However, I am struggling with a number of possible inconsistencies between stand-alone R scripts vs Markdown html layouts, and I wonder if that is due to bugs in my source code that I am unable to identify.
In particular, I am trying to reproduce a funnel plot, as shown by the following test code:
    library(plyr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(plotly)
    library(crosstalk)

    area <- c('TO1', 'TO2', 'BOLOGNA', 'BARI')
    regione <- c("Piemonte","Piemonte","Emilia Romagna","Puglie")
    ami_pct <- c(12.5, 7.4, 8.2, 10.0)
    N <- c(440, 230, 350, 120)
    df <- data.frame(area,ami_pct, N)

    # FUNNEL PLOT

    alpha_1<-0.05
    alpha_2<-0.002

    y<-df$ami_pct
    n<-df$N

    p_mean <- 7.65 
    p_max  <- max( y, na.rm=TRUE)
    p_min  <- min( y, na.rm=TRUE)
    p_ave  <- mean( y, na.rm=TRUE)
    p_N    <- sum( n, na.rm=TRUE)

    p_se <- sqrt( ( p_mean / 100 ) * (1 - ( p_mean / 100 ) ) )

    n <- n[which(!is.na(n))]

    # lower and upper limits for 95% and 99.8% CI, based on FEM estimator

    z_value1<-qnorm( 1 - alpha_1/2)
    z_value2<-qnorm( 1 - alpha_2/2)

    max_step<-round((max(n)-min(n))*0.005)
    if (max_step==0) {max_step<-1}
    n.seq  <- seq(min(n),max(n),max_step)

    n.ll95 <- (p_mean/100 - z_value1 * (p_se / sqrt(n.seq))) * 100
    n.ul95 <- (p_mean/100 + z_value1 * (p_se / sqrt(n.seq))) * 100
    n.ll99 <- (p_mean/100 - z_value2 * (p_se / sqrt(n.seq))) * 100
    n.ul99 <- (p_mean/100 + z_value2 * (p_se / sqrt(n.seq))) * 100

    dfCI <- as.data.frame(cbind(n.ll95, n.ul95, n.ll99, n.ul99, n.seq, p_mean*100))

    hline <- function(y = 0, color = "blue") {
      list(
        type = "line", 
        x0 = 0, 
        x1 = 1, 
        xref = "paper",
        y0 = y, 
        y1 = y, 
        line = list(color = color))
    }

    h_y<-max(df[,c("ami_pct")],na.rm=TRUE)+0.10*max(df[,c("ami_pct")],na.rm=TRUE)
    h_x<-max(df$N,na.rm=TRUE)+0.10*max(df$N,na.rm=TRUE)

    sd      <- SharedData$new(df,group = "shared_obj") # NOTE HERE THE SHARED DATASET

    fig <- plot_ly(width=680) %>%
      add_trace(data=sd,
                type = "scatter",
                mode = "markers",
                x = ~N,
                y = ~ami_pct,
                color= ~regione,text = ~paste("Area: ", area, "<br>","%",":",ami_pct,"<br>N:",N,sep=""))   %>%
      layout(yaxis = list(title = paste("<b>","%","<b>",sep=""), range=c(0,h_y)),
             xaxis = list(title = "<b>Total Number of CASES<b>", range=c(0,h_x)),
             legend = list(font = list(size=12)),
             shapes = list(hline(p_mean)))  %>%
     add_trace(data=dfCI,
               type="scatter",
               x = ~n.seq,
               y = ~n.ul95,
               mode = "lines",
               line = list(dash = "solid",color = "blue", width = 0.5),
               showlegend = FALSE,
               hoverinfo="none") %>%
     add_trace(data=dfCI,
               type="scatter",
               x = ~n.seq,
               y = ~n.ll95,
               mode = "lines",
               line = list(dash = "solid",color = "blue", width = 0.5),
               showlegend = FALSE,
               hoverinfo="none"
              ) %>%
     add_trace(data=dfCI,
               type="scatter",
               x = ~n.seq,
               y = ~n.ll99,
               mode = "lines",
               line = list(dash = "dash" ,color = "blue", width = 0.5),
               showlegend = FALSE,
               hoverinfo="none") %>%
     add_trace(data=dfCI,
               type="scatter",
               x = ~n.seq,
               y = ~n.ul99,
               mode = "lines",
               line = list(dash = "dash" ,color = "blue", width = 0.5),
               showlegend = FALSE,
               hoverinfo="none")

    fig

This works fairly well and produces the expected results:

However, when using markdown in the following file [debug.so.Rmd], the control limits (essential) ARE NOT SHOWN......I tried all sort of things.....any hints?
    ---
    title: "Test"
    author: "F.Carinci"
    output:
     flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
      orientation: columns
      theme: paper
      vertical-layout: fill
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(plyr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(plotly)
    library(crosstalk)

    area <- c('TO1', 'TO2', 'BOLOGNA', 'BARI')
    regione <- c("Piemonte","Piemonte","Emilia Romagna","Puglie")
    ami_pct <- c(12.5, 7.4, 8.2, 10.0)
    N <- c(440, 230, 350, 120)
    df <- data.frame(area,ami_pct, N)

    # FUNNEL PLOT

    alpha_1<-0.05
    alpha_2<-0.002

    y<-df$ami_pct
    n<-df$N

    p_mean <- 7.65 
    p_max  <- max( y, na.rm=TRUE)
    p_min  <- min( y, na.rm=TRUE)
    p_ave  <- mean( y, na.rm=TRUE)
    p_N    <- sum( n, na.rm=TRUE)

    p_se <- sqrt( ( p_mean / 100 ) * (1 - ( p_mean / 100 ) ) )

    n <- n[which(!is.na(n))]

    # lower and upper limits for 95% and 99.8% CI, based on FEM estimator

    z_value1<-qnorm( 1 - alpha_1/2)
    z_value2<-qnorm( 1 - alpha_2/2)

    max_step<-round((max(n)-min(n))*0.005)
    if (max_step==0) {max_step<-1}
    n.seq  <- seq(min(n),max(n),max_step)

    n.ll95 <- (p_mean/100 - z_value1 * (p_se / sqrt(n.seq))) * 100
    n.ul95 <- (p_mean/100 + z_value1 * (p_se / sqrt(n.seq))) * 100
    n.ll99 <- (p_mean/100 - z_value2 * (p_se / sqrt(n.seq))) * 100
    n.ul99 <- (p_mean/100 + z_value2 * (p_se / sqrt(n.seq))) * 100

    dfCI <- as.data.frame(cbind(n.ll95, n.ul95, n.ll99, n.ul99, n.seq, p_mean*100))

    hline <- function(y = 0, color = "blue") {
      list(
        type = "line", 
        x0 = 0, 
        x1 = 1, 
        xref = "paper",
        y0 = y, 
        y1 = y, 
        line = list(color = color))
    }

    h_y<-max(df[,c("ami_pct")],na.rm=TRUE)+0.10*max(df[,c("ami_pct")],na.rm=TRUE)
    h_x<-max(df$N,na.rm=TRUE)+0.10*max(df$N,na.rm=TRUE)

    sd      <- SharedData$new(df,group = "shared_obj") # Markers
    ```

    ## Input {.sidebar}

    **Select quality results**
    ```{r filter3}
    filter_slider(id = "Target",label = "%",sharedData = sd,column = ~ami_pct,step = 1,round = TRUE)
    ```

    ## Column {data-width="700"}

    ### Map

    ```{r map}

    ```
    ## Column {data-width="240"}

    ### valuebox1 {data-height="70"}

    ```{r}
    ```

    ### valuebox2 {data-height="70"}

    ```{r}
    ```

    ### valuebox3 {data-height="70"}

    ```{r}
    ```

    ### valuebox4 {data-height="70"}

    ```{r}
    ```

    ### valuebox5 {data-height="70"}

    ```{r}
    ```

    ## Column {data-width="680"}

    ###  Funnel plot {data-height="700"}

    ```{r}
    fig <- plot_ly(width=680) %>%
      add_trace(data=sd,
                type = "scatter",
                mode = "markers",
                x = ~N,
                y = ~ami_pct,
                color= ~regione,text = ~paste("Area: ", area, "<br>","%",":",ami_pct,"<br>N:",N,sep=""))   %>%
      layout(yaxis = list(title = paste("<b>","%","<b>",sep=""), range=c(0,h_y)),
             xaxis = list(title = "<b>Total Number of CASES<b>", range=c(0,h_x)),
             legend = list(font = list(size=12)),
             shapes = list(hline(p_mean)))  %>%
     add_trace(data=dfCI,
               type="scatter",
               x = ~n.seq,
               y = ~n.ul95,
               mode = "lines",
               line = list(dash = "solid",color = "blue", width = 0.5),
               showlegend = FALSE,
              hoverinfo="none") %>%
     add_trace(data=dfCI,
               type="scatter",
               x = ~n.seq,
               y = ~n.ll95,
               mode = "lines",
               line = list(dash = "solid",color = "blue", width = 0.5),
               showlegend = FALSE,
               hoverinfo="none"
              ) %>%
     add_trace(data=dfCI,
               type="scatter",
               x = ~n.seq,
               y = ~n.ll99,
               mode = "lines",
               line = list(dash = "dash" ,color = "blue", width = 0.5),
               showlegend = FALSE,
               hoverinfo="none") %>%
     add_trace(data=dfCI,
               type="scatter",
               x = ~n.seq,
               y = ~n.ul99,
               mode = "lines",
               line = list(dash = "dash" ,color = "blue", width = 0.5),
               showlegend = FALSE,
               hoverinfo="none")

    fig


    ```

    ### Datatable

    ```{r datatable}    
    ```


Right now crosstalk is replacing all data. Using different dataframes for the different aspects of your plot is a problem with crosstalk <-> plotly. (this is my best guess!) You could use Plotly's rangeslider; you could use Shiny's inputselector (or the like), a more complicated approach could be through the library htmltools or using a JS chunk to manager the input controls.  -- I see that you're new to SO - awesome work putting together your first question (much better than I did in the beginning!)
